# How to check if new opened tab is active (page is in front) in Playwright

Tags: typescript, playwright

I have simple scenario. Clicking GitHub link on `playwright.dev` tiggers opening new tab.

How to assert that this page was opened and is in front (⚠️without checking page elements).

Does page has some attributes what shows this state (like `isClosed()`)?

Example code (where all in newly opened page is dropped):

```js
import { expect, test } from "@playwright/test";

test("should redirect user to new tab after using clicking link", async ({
  page,
  context,
}) => {
  // Arrange
  const expectedUrl = "https://github.com/microsoft/playwright";

  await page.goto("https://playwright.dev/");
  await page.waitForLoadState();
  const newTabPromise = page.waitForEvent("popup");

  await context.route("**/*", (route) => route.abort());
  let observedURL = "unknown";
  context.on("request", (request) => {
    observedURL = request.url();
  });

  // Act
  await page.getByRole("link", { name: "GitHub repository" }).click();
  const newTab = await newTabPromise;

  // Assert
  expect(observedURL).toContain(expectedUrl);
  expect(newTab.isClosed()).toBe(false);
  // assert here that page is focused 
});
```